# How to calculate a working "AllowedIPs" for Wireguard on Android?

Tags: ip, subnet, wireguard

I am using Android to connect to my WireGuard server through the public IP address of the host network. The LAN is using addresses `192.168.0.1-255`. I would like the client to connect through the VPN only to addresses with in the LAN and directly access the others. The config is as follows:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxx=
Address = 198.18.7.4/32
DNS = 192.168.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.1/24
Endpoint = my.public.IP:51820
```

But I am getting a "Bad Address" for whatever I tried to use except for `/32`. Not being familiar with Subnet Address scheme, I tried to use the table and calculator [here](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html?cclass=c&csubnet=24&cip=192.168.0.1&ctype=ipv4&printit=0&x=84&y=16) which seems to tell me that /24 is the correct subnet. On Windows this seems to work fine.

Any Idea what can be wrong here? Is the AllowedIPs  wrong? Or is there an issue with Android that is not in my control?

Thanks!

Comment: did you set in the client or server? both must afaik match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AllowedIPs` setting is wrong -- it must be a proper subnet: `192.168.0.0/24`, not `192.168.0.1/24`.

(It's confusing because the `Address` setting *can* be specified using the same notation -- eg `198.18.7.4/24` -- but in that case, it means the interface's address is `198.18.7.4` on the `198.18.7.0/24` subnet.)

Comment: Thanks! What confused me as well is that Windows does not seem to have an issue with the wrong setting...